# Have an if statement where several tests are done with the same output

Tags: java, android

I am programming for Android and I have several cases where I test multiple strings but use the same return, for example:

```
if (s.contentEquals("caer"))    {
    out(a);
    yo("igo");
}
if (s.contentEquals("traer"))   {
    out(a);
    yo("igo");
}
```

Is there a way to test all these cases at once, and if one of those is true then do the return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
if (s.contentEquals("caer") || s.contentEquals("traer")) {
    out(a);
    yo("igo");
}
```

Comment: +1. Other than the bizarre closing brace position, this is a good answer :-) Modified it to match the OP's original style (indentation as well), always a good idea so they can simply cut'n'paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more Strings you wanna try than those two it might be a time saver to store them all in an array and do something like this:

```
String[] stringsToTest = {"h", "de", "ej"};

for (String d : stringsToTest) 
{
    if(s.contentsEquals(d)
    {
        out(a);
        yo("igo");
}
```

Another alternative is to store the Strings you want to have tested in a list and ask for an iterator, but that's not as clean as the above for each-loop in my opinion.

Comment: Sort the stringsToTest and use Arrays.binarySearch(..) when you've got waay to many strings to test for a match. Supply a case insensitive comparator if that's your thing.